# why does my javascript code for changing(onclick) the div opacity fail?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, opacity

```
<a id = "click_show_more" href = "" onclick = "showMore()">
    <li id = "more">
    MORE
    </li>
</a>
<div id = "more_hidden">
    <ul id = "list_hidden">
    <li>EFG</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above is my html code. I want to call the javascript function "showMore()" when clicking on a the link "MORE" with id "click_show_more".

This is my javascript code.

```
function showMore() {
    var moreShow = document.getElementById('more_hidden');
    moreShow.style.opacity = 0.8;
}
```

I don't know why this code fails. Nothing happens when I clicked on the link.

Please help me figure it out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `href` attribute from your link or set it to something like `#` so that a page won't be loaded. You are linking to another page (or the same page) with that.

Further, your html is invalid. `<li>` does not belong as a child of `<a>`.

See this demo with your markup corrected demonstrating the difference between the link with the href and with it removed. http://jsbin.com/iJEDiku/2/edit

Please don't use inline javascript (like `onclick` in your html). Study about this here: [Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)

Here's your code following better practices. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iJEDiku/3/edit)

**Markup:**

```
<a id="change-opacity">Click here to change opacity.</a>
<div id="opacity-gets-changed">
  <ul>
    <li>EFG</li>
    <li>ABC</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var a = document.getElementById('change-opacity');
var div = document.getElementById('opacity-gets-changed');

a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  div.style.opacity = 0.4;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your key explanations!